Where can I set up Power Query to automatically update the steps to transform the sample file?
I have two sample file in Power Query:
Two sample file
One is automatically update the steps if I change something in it:
Auto-updating sample
And second isn't updating automatically, and as shown in the picture, there is no option to turn it off:
Not updating sample
Is there any option to turn on this auto-update and if I can, where is it?

If you're using folder source to combine files, sometimes I think it's easier to just go through the steps to connect to the folder again. However, you should be able to right click your query and select "Create Function" in order to link a function to an existing query. Then if you have a query that needs to call or invoke this function then you can update the function name to be the one you just created / linked.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/custom-function

